# How do I solve Application.Worksheetfunction.Match error?

Tags: excel, vba

I searched net for answer but nothing worked (found 5-6~ different solutions but neither worked for me.

I'm getting 1004 error for Application Match. What it does in my case it should give a range from Data sheet to Column E_Menu - "menu" so I could choose one entry from a list of already created and edit it, but for some reason it won't work.

I tried defining column E_menu, changing variants for Range ("xxxxx") which originaly was Dyn_Full_Name or smth but it wouldnt work either.

````
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim TargetRow As Integer 
```TargetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ColumnE_Menu, Sheets("Data").Range(Cell1:="B2", Cell2:="D4"), 0)```
Sheets("Engine").Range("B5").Value = TargetRow for use later

Unload Find_Entry_UF 

'''Begin retrieving data from database'''
Data_UF.Txt_Update = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 2).Value 'first name
Data_UF.Txt_Description = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 3).Value 'surname
Data_UF.Txt_Owner = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 4).Value 'age
Data_UF.Txt_Proc = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 6).Value 'gender combo box
Data_UF.Combo_Status = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 7).Value 'region combo box
'''End retrieving data from database'''

Data_UF.Caption = "Edit Existing" 'set caption to show that the user is editing
Data_UF.Show 'show the user form with the details loaded in

End Sub
````

Comment: `Match` requires a one column or one row range.

Comment: and how do I do that  I can use column B for example theres index numbers from 1 to last entry

Comment: Change the match range to something like `Sheets("Data").Range("B2:B4")` or however many rows it needs to be.

Comment: I tried that too it was my first guess to change dynamic range to smth like B8:B11 but it gave same error

Comment: Then your lookup value isn't being found.